# ASCII to Base64 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, base64, ascii

I'm trying to pull an image via GET /url.jpg and in the response is the image's ASCII representation. I then take that and try to Base64 encode it so I can display the image via html in an src tag. Here's the code I'm using:

```
api.getImg()
    .then(function(res){
        var reader = new window.FileReader();
        var data = new Blob([res.data], {type: 'image/jpg'});

        reader.readAsDataURL(data);
        reader.onloadend = function() {
            // sets the base64 encoded image to ng-src via AngularJS
            vm.imgVis.viz1.link = reader.result;

        }
    });
```

The encoded image is then passed into the ng-src tag and nothing is loaded, broken image. I then take the base64 string to online base64 to image converters and nothing works there either.

Next, I tried directly uploading the image into an 'image to base64' converter and I get a completely new base64 string that works just fine anywhere I use it. Additionally, I turned this new string into an ASCII format and it looks nearly identical to the original GET response, however it appears the unprinted ASCII chars such as NULL are not being represented the same.

I think my issue might be with the ASCII character set. Could that be my problem? I feel like I'm missing a step.

Thanks

Edited to add API call:

```
function getImg() {
    var settings = {
      "url": "assets/apple.jpg",
      "method": "GET",
      "headers": {}
    }
    return $http(settings)
        .then(function(response) {
            return response;
        })
        .catch(function(e) {
            return e;
        }); 
}
```

And here is the actual image:
[Apple](http://www.u7solutions.com/files/u7solutions/client-files/inline-images/apple-large.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean by "ASCII representation"? Could what you see as ASCII actually be binary data?

Comment: That would explain NULL

Comment: try `console.log` with `reader.result`, and then paste that url into new tab, if it works then there is no issue in your code. try changing your image.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice It is the binary data yes.

Comment: @shyammakwana.me When I do that, I get a small box with nothing in it. However when i use this website: https://www.base64-image.de/ and use the encoded data from there doing what you suggested, it works fine. It also works fine in my app.

Comment: then there is an issue with your code. try logging every variable, possibly there is problem with `data`.

Comment: `res` is the response object from the GET I perform via `api.getImg()` and `res.data` is the binary representation of the image from the response object. At this point, the image is being fetched from my desktop. I'm not doing anything else other than reading and trying to convert it to base64.

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle for this code?